# State machine workflow and persistance

Tags: wcf, oracle, workflow, persistence, state-machine

I am working on a state machine workflow in 4.0.1 which is called from a WCF service. I am dynamically creating the proxy and calling the activity in workflow.
I am using Oracle as backend. 
Can anyone help me to implement persistance for this workflow. I want to persist the workflow to Oracle database or to file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with DevExpress.  They have created an Instance Store provider that supports Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Devart has developed an Instance Store provider that supports Oracle too.